# How to do a multiple Post Requests in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

Hello I want to do multiple post requests based on some conditions. I am trying but my code isn't working. I have a database stored online(Firebase). What I do is I fetch the data from online and save into localdb and then delete the online data.

This is what I am doing so far

```
request('http://my-url here', function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error);
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); Print the response status code if a response was received

    var data = [];
    var parse = JSON.parse(body);

    var ids =  Object.keys(parse);
     var i = 0;

   ids.forEach(function(id) {
   var unique_keys =  Object.keys(parse[id]);
        unique_keys.forEach(function(unique_key) {

            data[i] = [

                    parse[id][unique_key]["lat"],
                    parse[id][unique_key]["long"],



                ];
                i++;
   });

 });

    saveHistory(data, function (result) {

        console.log("successfully save into local db");
        removeDataFromOnlineDatabase
        process.exit();

    });





}); 

function removeHistoryFromOnlineDatabase(){

    var request = require("request");

   console.log("function get called");
    var options = { method: 'DELETE',
        url: 'url here',
        headers:
            { 'Postman-Token': '4a126ab8-9b3e-465d-b827-d4dd83923610',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);

        console.log("history has been removed" + body);
    });

}
```

I have tried this above code but this  function `removeHistoryFromOnlineDatabase` post request don't work

the function get called and it prints "function get called" But it doesn't print "history has been removed"

Comment: `removeHistoryFromOnlineDatabase post request don't work` means you get any error? or function not called... what exactly happened?

Comment: @HardikShah I have updated my question

Comment: Have you try running removeHistoryFromOnlineDatabase() alone? Is it the same as running together with the other lines of code?

Comment: No I just supply the url and method delete in it. If I try to call this function outside of first post request then it gets called successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `process.exit();` below `console.log("history has been removed" + body);`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling function and then immediate line exited the process by `process.exit()` before your `removeHistoryFromOnlineDatabase` function execution.

**Please Note:-** I have removed your option JSON data for smaller code.

---

**Way 1:** (Use `Callback`) *(Only Callback)*

```
saveHistory(data, function (result) {

    console.log("successfully save into local db");
    removeDataFromOnlineDatabase(function(error, response){
       process.exit();
    })

});

function removeHistoryFromOnlineDatabase(callback){
  var request = require("request");
  console.log("function get called");
  var options = options;

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error){
     callback(error, null); 
    } else {
     console.log("history has been removed" + body);
     callback(null, response) 
    }
  });
}
```

---

**Way 2:** (Use `Promise`) *(Only promise)*

```
var Q = require("q");

saveHistory(data, function (result) {
    console.log("successfully save into local db");
    removeDataFromOnlineDatabase()
    .then(function(){
      process.exit();
    }).catch(function(){
       console.log("ERROR IN REQUEST");
    });
});

function removeHistoryFromOnlineDatabase(){
  var request = require("request");
  console.log("function get called");
  var options = options;

  return Q.promise(function(resolve, reject){
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error){
        reject(error);
      } else {
        console.log("history has been removed" + body);
        resolve(response) 
      }
    });
  });

}
```

---

**Way 3:** (Using `promise - Q.nfcall`) *(callback + promise)*

```
var Q = require("q");

saveHistory(data, function (result) {
    console.log("successfully save into local db");
    Q.nfcall(removeDataFromOnlineDatabase)
    .then(function(){
      process.exit();
    }).catch(function(){
       console.log("ERROR IN REQUEST");
    });
});

function removeHistoryFromOnlineDatabase(callback){
  var request = require("request");
  console.log("function get called");
  var options = options;

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error){
     callback(error, null); 
    } else {
     console.log("history has been removed" + body);
     callback(null, response) 
    }
  });

}
```